# C++ Write file to C drive

Tags: c++, windows, file

My program lets the user specify where to write a file. If they specify "C:\output.txt" the file operations seem to succeed (no errors) however the file doesn't get created. I know this is due to Windows requiring elevated permission and when running as administrator it does write to C:\. My question is how can I detect that the file didn't actually open?

This block "succeeds" without error even though the file doesn't actually get created:

```
ofstream ofs;
try {
    ofs.open(outputFile);
    if (!ofs.is_open()){
        throw "The file could not be opened";
    }
    ofs << "it worked";
    ofs.close();
} catch (const char* ex){
    cout << ex;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: If you don't have permission to create the file, `is_open()` should return false.

Comment: Are you sure, the file is not created and still gives is_open turns true? Try this: if ( (ofs.rdstate() & std::ofstream::failbit ) != 0 ) instead of ofs.is_open. Update if you find the correct solution.

Comment: Try using forward slash in filenames, such as "C:/outfile.txt"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `open()` fails to create/open a file, the stream's `is_open()` method will return false, and the stream's `failbit` state flag will be set, so the `fail()` method and `operator!` will return true:

```
ofs.open(outputFile);
if (!ofs.is_open())
// or: if (ofs.fail())
// or: if (!ofs)
{
    cout << "The file could not be opened";
    return 1;
}
```

If no failure is reported, then no failure occurred.  The file was created *somewhere*, but that *might* not be where you are expecting.

If you open a file using a relative path, then it is relative to the calling process's current working directory, which may be different than you are expecting.  So always use absolute paths.

If you try to create a file and you don't have access to the folder where you are creating the file, the file creation might get transparently redirected to a `VirtualStore` folder within the user's profile instead.

Try using [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see *where* exactly the file is being created (or even, where `open()` is *attempting* to create the file, if no access is allowed and redirection doesn't happen).

---

On a side note, what you showed is a misuse of exception handling.  You don't really need an exception at all, as shown above.  However, if you do want to throw an exception on failure, consider using the [`ofstream::exceptions()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions) method instead:

```
ofstream ofs;
ofs.exceptions(ofstream::failbit);
try {
    ofs.open(outputFile);
    ofs << "it worked";
}
catch (std::ios_base::failure &) {
    cout << "The file could not be opened, or written to";
    return 1;
}
ofs.close();
```

Comment: It's almost certainly VirtualStore redirection, given the observed symptoms, so you might want to emphasize that part of the answer more and maybe give some examples.

Comment: That wasn't the question that was asked, though - "*how can I detect that the file didn't actually open?*".  The first part of my answer explains how to check that. The second part explains how the file *could* be created without being where the OP expected it to be.  Different issue than the one asked.

Comment: He already knows how to tell if no file was opened, so it's useless to answer that.  Explaining the difference between "no file opened" and "file activity redirected to another path and succeeds there" is the thing that's going to help

Comment: Using sysinternals procmon I was able to see that the file output was redirected to C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\ - is there a way to determine where the file was actually written to notify the user?

Comment: @koga73 not with `ofstream `, no. Use [`CreateFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx) instead, and then you can use [`GetFinalPathNameByHandle()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364962.aspx)